I just got a popup from OpenSnitch indicating an outgoing connection from sshd. Should I nuke my disk?
I just got a popup from OpenSnitch indicating that sshd (not ssh) wants to establish an outgoing connection to an IP in China (120.78.150.45). The popup was only around for a short period, so I didn't get a screenshot of it, but I have a screenshot of the log panel in OpenSnitch.
Thinking this might be caused by just random SSH traffic, I tried logging in from my phone over LTE. That did not produce the popup again.

What could be the cause of this? sshd normally receives incoming connections, not making outgoing ones.
Should I nuke my disk?

I have checked /var/log/auth.log and see no evidence of login, not that that's a robust intrusion detection.

UPDATE: I was playing with SSH and I can make the server trigger this popup again by supplying the -W flag when connecting. The outgoing connection from the server only happens after successful authentication, making me wary of a breach. Are there any other flags that could make this happen?

Is that all the log panel shows? Does it have a Source column available?

"sshd normally receives incoming connections, not making outgoing ones" -- I think if a user of ssh specifies -L (or -D) and actually uses the tunnel (or proxy, respectively), then sshd on the server will make outgoing connections for the user.

Unfortunately no other columns available. Obviously if someone did some tunneling, I'm compromised. Are there any other SSH flags that could trigger an outgoing connection before successful authentication?

Does your auth.log mention any connection attempts from 120.78.150.45?

Actually, no. Making me worried that they've altered the logs?
